# Javascript function returns different results on test site and live site

Tags: javascript

This is my first post.
Im fairly new to javascript, and was trying to use the following function to grab the document name, (which is mimicked by an element id on the page) to be used in a later function.  on the testing site, it works perfectly.  for example, if the file is `http://testserver/options/example.html` it returns 'example'

one the live site, it always returns `www`

```
<script  type="text/javascript">  

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var pageName = function() {
    //this gets the full url
    var url = document.location.href; 
    //this removes the anchor at the end, if there is one
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("#") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("#")); 
    //this removes the query after the file name, if there is one
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("?") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("?")); console.log(url);
    //this removes the file extension, if there is one 
    url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf(".") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf(".")); console.log(url);
    //this removes everything before the last slash in the path
    url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length); console.log(url);
    //return
    return url; console.log(url);
    }

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: This seems like it'd be easier to do with `split()`.

Comment: @user1754706 First question here, please read [How to ask Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) esp, what to do when you get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying this line like so:

Your test site does not have all the "." like the live site does (i.e. www. or .com). By using lastIndexOf, you can get the last instance of the "." in the url which will be before the extension.

Change it from:

```
url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf(".") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("."));
```

To:

```
url = url.substring(0, (url.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) ? url.length : url.lastIndexOf("."));
```

For more information on lastIndexOf visit this link:

[lastIndexOf() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)

Hope this helps.

Comment: it did, i feel very silly for not realizing that immediately. thanks for your time.

Comment: Make sure to mark his response as the answer if it fixed your problem